# Error in plotting a function

Tags: matlab, function

I am trying to build and plot a Triangular function with an amplitude of 1, starting in second 1, reaching the max in second 3 and going back to zero in second 4,

- `x(A, t1, t2, t3, t) = A/t2-t1 * (t-t1)`, when `t1 <= t <= t2`
- `x(A, t1, t2, t3, t) = A/t2-t3 * (t-t3)`, when `t2 <= t < t3`
- `x(A, t1, t2, t3, t) = 0` elsewhere

The problem is that I can't find a way to add the two conditions to the function, even with one condition I keep getting this error:

```
Error in Untitled1 (line 6)
x2 = mytri(A,t1,t2,t3,t);
```

---

Here is what I've got so far, please give me an idea to how to add them both and not get errors:

```
fs = 20;       %freq
t = 0:1/fs:5;
t1=1;
t2=3;
t3=4;
A=1;           %amplitude

x2 = mytri(A, t1, t2, t3, t);
plot (t,x2,'.-')
axis([ -2 5 -2 5])
```

The function:

```
function x2 = mytri(A, t1, t2, t3, t)
    x2 = A/t2 - t1*t - t1*(t1 <= t <= t2);
```

Comment: Hint: on the command line, check the difference between `t1<=t<=t2` and `t1<=t&t<=t2`.

Comment: ok I tried, and gave me different answers , but this doesn't solve the problem of having different conditions for the same function..

Comment: Simplest way: preallocate an empty zero vector of length `t`, then fill in the correct values for each of your two conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that manually manually creates the rising and falling portions of the triangle waveform given a percentage/duty cycle of the waveform and a period T.

```
T = 3;              % period in secs
rise_pct = 2/3;     % percentage of wave rising
fall_pct = 1/3;     % percentage of wave falling
dt = 0.01;          % time interval

N_repeats = 2;

rise = linspace(0,1,T*rise_time/dt);    % create rising section
fall = linspace(1,0,T*fall_time/dt);    % create fallingsection
wave = [rise,fall];                     % join rise and fall strokes

wave = repmat(wave,1,N_repeats); %repeat wave

t = (1:length(wave)).*dt + 1; %time vec starting at 1sec
plot(t,wave);
```

Comment: thanks, but this isn't just about the 'triangle' it's about creating a specific function with specific amplitudes and time intervals  ..